# Edit on duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Since there is a facility to edit the question which is marked as a duplicate is available, the user can edit the question almost *entirely* including the title of the question.

So after the edit, the question may look entirely different from the first one. But the duplicate tag will be attached to the question even after the edit is made. Now, if a new user looks into the question it may be unclear to him why the question is marked as a duplicate.

I think there should be some revision of the tags after the edit is made. Or the edit should be disabled after the question is marked as a duplicate.

At least the title should be kept disabled.

Comment: While this sounds like a potentially damaging scenario in theory, in practice there are already many safeguards in place that prevent destructive edits like the one you describe from being a major problem.  One of those safeguards is a comprehensive edit history that is readily available for each question, which provides full accountability for community members making edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some points here:

- If a question is closed as a duplicate, then it is edited with entirely different question, such question goes to [the reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) where a question can be reopened by community.
- If a question is not reopened after such edits, we can always see the revision of any question by clicking on a last edited link (e.g. "edited XX hours ago"). Where we can see all revisions of the question including closing event.
- I disagree to disabling editing after it is closed because improving a post is always welcomed here.

Comment: Improving posts is okay.But since the edit on title is also possible, The user can make the posts look like entirely a new one. which may lead to some misunderstandings in users minds about the duplicate tag

Comment: @ddMyth2857356 - That's why we have a chance to reopen the post. If the user keeps editing his question in such way (multiple time on the same question), a moderator can lock the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you check a post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030296/technical-term-for-accessing-an-array-with-an-index-and-square-brackets), and click here:

[image: revision link]

You will get a nice summary of what revisions were made when, including when the question was closed, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21030296/revisions):

[image: revision history]

If you notice that the question looks different from the duplicate question and has been edited, you can always look at the revision history to see what's going on.

Locking edits would be bad because it would prevent users from improving their questions. Perhaps they already saw the duplicate question but it didn't solve their problem, or there was something different there. Maybe there is some small distinction that makes it something other than an **exact** duplicate. The goal is to make sure that the question has a chance of being reopened if it can be salvaged.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, editing after a closure is okay, since some house-keeping may be in order once a duplicate is established (like retagging, or perhaps even providing a more suitable title). So, it's definitely acceptable or at least conceivable to edit a post after closure.

Second, there are some mechanisms in place to help avoid against possible abuse. Most notably would be the "re-open review queue". Questions that were edited/altered after closure is up for review by eligible community members. Also, edited posts tend to float to the top of the visible queue for everyone to see, where some people do most of their housekeeping (and possibly pick up that some abuse has occurred).

Finally, if you notice this, you can jump into action and revert any improper edits by rolling back to a previous revision, or flag the post for moderator attention.